# Failed to create behavior assisted_teleop of type nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going through the [Getting Started](https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html#installation) in Nav2 Docs. I have installed `navigation2`, `nav2-bringup` and `turtlebot3` packages using the following commands:

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-navigation2
sudo apt install ros-humble-nav2-bringup
sudo apt install ros-humble-turtlebot3*
```

As per the tutorial I source and exported the required environment variables by:

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models
```

But when I launch the `nav2_bringup` using the following launch command I get the below listed error:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/77fe00b8702ce7e729c5d1af7e017e68

I get a Rviz and Gazebo windows opened without any TurtleBot. How do I resolve the **nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop with base class type nav2_core::Behavior does not exist** exception and the **spawn service** failure?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411574/failed-to-create-behavior-assisted_teleop-of-type-nav2_behaviors/assistedteleop/) by [tsadarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/70847/tsadarsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2023-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently, I had some missing packages. I solved this issue by running:

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-nav*
```

---

Originally posted by [tsadarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/70847/tsadarsh/) with karma: 78 on 2023-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0